# Android /java Time Format?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I have time as  a "2011-12-03 12:00:19" how to convert it in "Fri 2 December 2011 " ,I know this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html ,But gives me Error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
    at java.text.DateFormat.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.Format.format(Unknown Source)
    at com.timestamp.NewTimeStamp.<init>(NewTimeStamp.java:21)
    at com.timestamp.NewTimeStamp.main(NewTimeStamp.java:35)
```

My code is ::

```
String mytime ="2011-12-03 12:00:19";
String pattern = "EEE d MMMMM yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

        Date date = new Date(mytime);
        String time = dateFormat.format(date);

        System.out.println("=== > " + time);
```

Comment: String pattern = "EEE d MMMMM yyyy";

Comment: Date date = new Date(mytime); I think this line is giving you the error. put debug code System.out.println (  "1" )  & ( "2" ) before & after that line & then execute & see if that line really generates the error or what ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert your input to `Date` and then format.

```
        String mytime ="2011-12-03 12:00:19";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss");
        Date myDate = dateFormat.parse(mytime);
        System.out.println("=== > " + myDate);
        SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE d MMMMM yyyy");
        String time = timeFormat.format(myDate);
        System.out.println("=== > " + time);
```

Output:

```
D:\Work\Stand alone Java classes>javac Test2.java && java Test2
=== > Wed Jan 12 12:00:19 IST 2011
=== > Wed 12 January 2011
```

Comment: But wht abt month its return january actually it is december?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss"); is right